# complex analysis,Zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis

Question: Does the Riemann zeta function has an Anti-derivative ( some call it a primitive)?
( function F is a primitive for function f if the derivative of F equals f)
( i actually want to know about complex line integration of zeta function over a line segment , and that does it depend only on the end points of the line segment?)
( in which case we can use the complex counterpart of fundamental theorem of calculus )

i appreciate any suggestion . thanks

Comment: Did you show that $g(s) = \zeta(s)-\frac{1}{s-1}$ is entire ? So it has an entire anti-derivative $G(s)$ and any anti-derivative of $\zeta(s)$ is of the form $C+G(s)+\log(s-1)$. The branch of $\log(s-1)$ depends on which path you integrate $\zeta(s)$.

Answer (score 0):

No, it has no primitive. That's so because its residue at $1$ is not $0$ (actually, it is equal to $1$).

Comment: what about only in the critical strip ?

Comment: Yes, since the critical strip is simply connected.